# How can i write a byte object file from integers of different length of bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in programming and i want to write bytes from integers of different length to file  ex:

```
    my_list = [1, 2, 3200 , 60, 72000 ]
    with open(Path , "wb") as f:
        [f.write(i.to_bytes(3, "big")) for i in my_list]
```

to read this file i use :

```
    i, s = 0, 3
    with open(Path, "rb") as f:
        rb = f.read()
    print([int.from_bytes(rb[i:i+s], 'big') for i in range(i , len(rb), s)])
```

but this creats for every integer 3 bytes , and it's not a good method , is there a method to create dynamic bytes for each int and to read also , thank you in advance

Comment: From the stdlib: [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct).

Comment: You can check out `pickle` library as well

Comment: @SourinKarmakar thanks it work with pickle but not in struct thank you again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please think carefully about the program requirements. When you read the file, **how will you know** how many bytes to read for each value?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for the welcome, This is why the the function dumps looks like keep track of the structure of the object it return the same object with the loads function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the values in a format that isn't specific to Python then using binary file with the bytes is good.

If you want variable length of bytes to represent the integers to save space, then there are other ways to do this. For example you could use the gzip format.

Here is an example that uses the Python [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) library to create a file of a 1000 integers and compare it to non-gzip file with the same content.

It also uses the Python [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library to convert between integers into bytes

```py
import gzip
import struct
from pathlib import Path
import random

path = Path('/tmp/my_file.bin')
path_z = Path('/tmp/my_file.bin.gz')
random.seed('stackoverflow')
data_len = 1000
my_list = [random.randint(0, 16**4) for i in range(data_len)]
print(f"created list: {my_list[:4]}...")


with open(path, "wb") as f:
    data = struct.pack(f'>{data_len}I', *my_list)
    f.write(data)

with open(path, "rb") as f:
    rb = f.read()
    read_list = struct.unpack(f'>{data_len}I', rb)
print(f'Normal list: {read_list[:4]}...')
bin_file_size = path.stat().st_size
print(f"Normal Size: {bin_file_size} [bytes]")

with gzip.open(path_z, "wb") as f:
    data = struct.pack(f'>{data_len}I', *my_list)
    f.write(data)

with gzip.open(path_z, "rb") as f:
    rb = f.read()
    read_list = struct.unpack(f'>{data_len}I', rb)
print(f'gzip list: {read_list[:4]}...')
gzip_file_size = path_z.stat().st_size
print(f"gzip Size: {gzip_file_size} [bytes]")
print(f"shrunk to {gzip_file_size / bin_file_size * 100} %")
```

Which gave the following output:

```bash
$ python3 bytes_file.py 
created list: [36238, 568, 20603, 3324]...
Normal list: (36238, 568, 20603, 3324)...
Normal Size: 4000 [bytes]
gzip list: (36238, 568, 20603, 3324)...
gzip Size: 2804 [bytes]
shrunk to 70.1 %
```

These files are still readable by other programs:

```bash
$ od -A d --endian=big -t u4 --width=4 --read-bytes 16 /tmp/my_file.bin
0000000      36238
0000004        568
0000008      20603
0000012       3324
```

And also the gzip file:

```bash
$ gunzip -c /tmp/my_file.bin.gz | od -A d --endian=big -t u4 --width=4 --read-bytes 16
0000000      36238
0000004        568
0000008      20603
0000012       3324
```